# Excel VBA Range.FindNext method is unintentionally skipping some cells in the (multi-area) range

Tags: vba, excel

Part of a macro I've written goes through a table and checks for the highest values in a row/column. It goes from highest-to-smallest, so if the largest value in the table is 7, it'll go through and find all the 7s, do some code on them, then go back and find all the 6s, do some code on those, etc. (there's a picture below to help better explain this)

For some reason, even though I know the values that I'm looking for are in the range, `Range.FindNext` skips over some of the cells. Not only could this be a problem with getting the results I want, but some data sets cause the program to hang since the Do Until loop I have won't find the right cell, so it keeps looping forever.

Since the table can get pretty large (hundreds by hundreds), in the interest of efficiency, I stole a function from the internet to subtract ranges, intending to use it as "After you find all the 7s, take those cells out of the range, so you don't check those cells again the next 6 times the code is run." The code creates a multi-area range, and I think that might have something to do with this weird skipping behavior.

Here's a picture of the way the program is currently operating:

[Table with Code Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nptF7.png)

- The green area is `checkRange` -- the area currently being searched by `Range.FindNext`
- The white cells were searched on previous passes, and then taken out of the range (i.e. they used to be green cells, but after the Do Until loop, they were taken out)
- The blue cells are cells that *are* found by `FindNext` (in this iteration of the loop, it's looking for 2s)
- The yellow cell is the current `lastCell`; this changes if the current `lastCell` is a part of the range that is taken out of `checkRange` (so `checkRange.Find(What:=fnd, after:=lastCell)` doesn't refer to a cell outside of `checkRange`)

You can see that some cells are being skipped over; the code is searching for 2s, but there are some 2s that are still in the green area. In the current loop, the code is just repeating through the blue cells, which also means that the first 2 (cell Ae, which has been assigned to `firstFound`) never gets found, and the Do Until loops forever.

```
Private mrBuild As Range
Private blTaken() As Boolean
Private eopTaken() As Boolean
Private checkRange As Range

Sub DifficultMatches()

'Runs after the initial matching, to increase the number of matches by re-evaluating the lower matches

Dim tblrw As Integer
Dim tblcl As Integer
Dim tblRange As Range
Dim lastCell As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim foundRange As Range
Dim cellRange As Range
Dim degreeRange As Range
Dim fnd As String
Dim firstFound As String

'Size of the table (not including the headers)
tblrw = rw1 - 1
tblcl = rw2 - 1
Set checkRange = Table.Cells(tablehead + 2, tableleft + 2).Resize(tblrw, tblcl) 'rw1 as long, rw2 as long, Table as Worksheet, etc. are defined in other subroutines

'Create a spot in the array for every BL and EOP
ReDim blTaken(tablehead + rw1)
ReDim eopTaken(tableleft + rw2)


'Take away all of the 7s, then 6s, etc.
For i = 0 To cl2 - 3
    fnd = cl2 - 3 - i

    Set lastCell = checkRange.Areas(checkRange.Areas.Count).Cells(checkRange.Areas(checkRange.Areas.Count).Cells.Count)
    Set foundCell = checkRange.Find(What:=fnd, after:=lastCell)

    'Check to see if there are any instances of the match degree
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        firstFound = foundCell.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "No " & fnd & "s found"
        GoTo NextDegree
    End If

    'Start the range that includes all the found cells
    Set foundRange = foundCell

    'Start the range that includes all of the match degree
    Set degreeRange = foundCell

    'Find other matches until you've found them all
    '***This is the loop that endlessly repeats when foundCell.address never equals firstFound***
    Do Until foundCell Is Nothing

        'Find the next match
        Set foundCell = checkRange.FindNext(after:=foundCell)

        'Add the next cell to the match degree range
        Set degreeRange = Union(degreeRange, foundCell)

        'If the match is still not matched to a Baseline or EOP
        If blTaken(foundCell.Row) = False And eopTaken(foundCell.Column) = False Then

            'Add that match's address to the range of found cells (it's basically ctrl+clicking each instance)
            Set foundRange = Union(foundRange, foundCell)

        End If

        'See if you have cycled all the way around to the beginning
        If foundCell.Address = firstFound Then Exit Do

    Loop

    'Now you have the range of that match degree.
    'Take the current match degree and remove it from checkRange (hopefully making future searches faster)
    Set checkRange = SubtractRanges(checkRange, degreeRange)

    'Take each cell and mark them as taken in the arrays.
    For Each cell In foundRange.Cells
        Set cellRange = cell
        FindHighestBaseline cellRange
        blTaken(cell.Row) = True
        eopTaken(cell.Column) = True
    Next cell
NextDegree:
Next i



End Sub
```

The stolen SubtractRanges function:

```
Public Function SubtractRanges(rFirst As Range, rSecond As Range) As Range

Dim rInter As Range
Dim rReturn As Range
Dim rArea As Range

Set rInter = Intersect(rFirst, rSecond)
Set mrBuild = Nothing

If rInter Is Nothing Then 'No overlap
    Set rReturn = rFirst
ElseIf rInter.Address = rFirst.Address Then 'total overlap
    Set rReturn = Nothing
Else 'partial overlap
    For Each rArea In rFirst.Areas
        BuildRange rArea, rInter
    Next rArea
    Set rReturn = mrBuild
End If

Set SubtractRanges = rReturn

End Function

Sub BuildRange(rArea As Range, rInter As Range)

Dim rLeft As Range, rRight As Range
Dim rTop As Range, rBottom As Range

If Intersect(rArea, rInter) Is Nothing Then 'no overlap
    If mrBuild Is Nothing Then
        Set mrBuild = rArea
    Else
        Set mrBuild = Union(mrBuild, rArea)
    End If
Else 'some overlap
    If rArea.Columns.Count = 1 Then 'we've exhausted columns, so split on rows
        If rArea.Rows.Count > 1 Then 'if one cell left, don't do anything
            Set rTop = rArea.Resize(rArea.Rows.Count \ 2) 'split the range top to bottom
            Set rBottom = rArea.Resize(rArea.Rows.Count - rTop.Rows.Count).Offset(rTop.Rows.Count)
            BuildRange rTop, rInter 'rerun it
            BuildRange rBottom, rInter
        End If
    Else
        Set rLeft = rArea.Resize(, rArea.Columns.Count \ 2) 'split the range left to right
        Set rRight = rArea.Resize(, rArea.Columns.Count - rLeft.Columns.Count).Offset(, rLeft.Columns.Count)
        BuildRange rLeft, rInter 'rerun it
        BuildRange rRight, rInter
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

And FindHighestBaseline; the code is super incomplete, since this error has been giving me problems with finding the correct way to write the code, but I'm including it for completeness' sake.

```
Public Function FindHighestBaseline(match As Range)
Dim blRecord As Range
Dim eopRecord As Range
Dim equalMaxes As Range
Dim blSimRecord As Range
Dim blSimFind As Range
Dim blSimBeginning As String
Dim runningMatch() As Double
Dim checkBlRecord As Range
Dim untakenCheckBlRecord As Range

Set blRecord = Table.Cells(match.Row, tableleft + 2).Resize(1, rw2 - 1)
Set eopRecord = Table.Cells(tablehead + 2, match.Column).Resize(rw1 - 1, 1)

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(blRecord, WorksheetFunction.max(blRecord)) > 1 Then

    Set checkBlRecord = Intersect(blRecord, checkRange)

    'For each max in range, check if blTaken and eopTaken are false, then average weights.
    If Not checkBlRecord Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In checkBlRecord

            'Create range of untaken EOPs
            If eopTaken(cell.Column) = False Then
                If untakenCheckBlRecord Is Nothing Then Set untakenCheckBlRecord = cell
                Set untakenCheckBlRecord = Union(untakenCheckBlRecord, cell)
            End If

        Next cell

        'Create range of equal maxes
        If Not untakenCheckBlRecord Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell In untakenCheckBlRecord

                If untakenCheckBlRecord.Cells(Application.match(WorksheetFunction.max(untakenCheckBlRecord), untakenCheckBlRecord, 0)) = cell Then
                    If equalMaxes Is Nothing Then Set equalMaxes = cell
                    Set equalMaxes = Union(equalMaxes, cell)
                End If

            Next cell
        End If
    End If

    If Not equalMaxes Is Nothing Then
        'Average Weights
        Set blSimRecord = Similarities.Cells.Range("A:A").Find(What:=blRecord.Cells(1).Offset(0, -2))
        blSimBeginning = blSimRecord.Address
        Do Until blSimFind Is Nothing
            Set blSimFind = Similarities.Cells.Range("A:A").FindNext(after:=blSimFind)
            Set blSimRecord = Union(blSimRecord, blSimFind)
            If blSimFind.Address = blSimBeginning Then Exit Do
        Loop

        ReDim runningMatch(equalMaxes.Cells.Count)

        For i = 1 To equalMaxes.Cells.Count

            'For each match, go to Similarities and find the weight, then
            'put the weight into its position in the array.
            'Example: runningMatch(1) = 0.467

        Next i

        blSimRecord.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        For Each cell In equalMaxes
        Next cell

    End If
End If

If blRecord.Cells(Application.match(WorksheetFunction.max(blRecord), blRecord, 0)).Address = match.Address Then
End If

If eopRecord.Cells(Application.match(WorksheetFunction.max(eopRecord), eopRecord, 0)).Address = match.Address Then
End If

End Function
```

Apologies for the sloppy code, I'm learning as I go and knew zero VBA before I started this project. (Any critique or convention advice is welcome!)

So, what's up? Why does `FindNext` skip these cells, when I can see that they're still in `checkRange`?

### EDIT:

I wanted to clarify that not all data sets cause the code to hang; this set, for instance, runs completely:

[Table that still skips, but doesn't hang.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmT5E.png)

On the right side of the table is a key that shows which numbers should be in which colors. I put a line in the code right before `SubtractRanges` that said `checkRange.Interior.ColorIndex = fnd + 3`, so since `degreeRange` is taken out of `checkRange` every iteration, all 7s should be one color, all 6s the next, etc. This data set seems to start skipping when `fnd = 3`.

Comment: Have you done any basic error checking - stepping through your code, setting breakpoints, writing variable values to the locals window? You need to check the values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: @SJR Yep, the table provided is a result of me setting a break point in the Do Until loop, then when `fnd = 2`, I wrote `checkRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 4` to the Immediate window and put an extra line in the loop that said `foundCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6`. After watching the value of `foundCell` through enough loops, I could see that it was rotating through the same cells.